# Jquery-ajax success: triggered twice (jquery 3.5.1)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need your help. I have this code that works but sometime (it happens randomly) the success event is triggered twice and I would like to understand why.. May you help me please to understand what is wrong?

The "problem" with the success event triggered twice is that it seems that the script delete multiple rows in one time instead of deleting only one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.delc', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("click");
    var id2 = $(this).closest(".delc").attr('rel');
    var item = $(this).parent().parent();
    data_2 = 'id=' + id2;
    $('#mdl-avviso-customer').modal('show');
    $('#del-btn-customer').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();       
        $.ajax({
          url: 'php/del_customer.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: data_2,
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            $(item).fadeOut(300,function(){
                $(item).remove();
              });
          }
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why are you nesting the 2nd click event?

Comment: because i have a first click on an <a href='#'>Icon</a> and then it opens a modal form with a confirm button to delete the row

Comment: I understand the logic flow that got you there, but it's flawed, and is causing your ajax call to occur twice, thus resulting in success occurring twice. events shouldn't be nested within other events unless the nested event is on an element created within the parent event. Otherwise... you'll re-bind the event every time the top most event occurs... resulting in multiples.

Comment: thanks for the information i'l try to modified the code and I will update this thread, thanks

Comment: @P.Davide Your nested event doesn't need to know that the first event has occurred, because the nested event can only happen if the user can see the button

Comment: thanks to all your comments i was able to fix the problem. I updated the thread and I hope that the way I found is good or at least good than the original one. Maybe there is a better and clean way to do the same thing but at least now it works without side effects.

All your answer where very usefull to me so tell me what to do know, how to close this thread in a good clean way. Thanks
Davide

Comment: It would be preferable, if you left the question as-is - and then provided the solution in an _answer_. That is likely to be more helpful to future readers, than an edited question that makes it hard to spot now, what the original problem was.

Comment: ok I do it right now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Correct code down below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var id;
      var item;
      var data;
      $(document).on('click', '.delc', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          console.log("click");
          id = $(this).closest('.delc').attr('rel');
          item = $(this).parent().parent();
          data = 'id=' + id;
          $('#mdl-avviso-customer').modal('show');
        });
        $('#del-btn-customer').on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();     
            $.ajax({
              url: 'php/del_customer.php',
              type: 'post',
              data: data,
              cache: false,
              success: function(html){
                $(item).fadeOut(300,function(){
                    $(item).remove();
                  });
              }
            });
        });  
    });
```